# when i put bottomnavigationview android studio | The design screen appears blank

Tags: screen, bottomnavigationview, blank-line, android-bottomnavigationview

when i put bottomnavigationview android studio | The design screen appears blank

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.chatsapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkpP.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change the height of the bottom navigation drawer from
   match_parent to wrap_content.
2. And also add constraints to the bottom navigation drawer view.

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
   ```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, maybe it's a newer version